# Are there any rings that are not polynomial identity rings?

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm currently studying polynomial rings and I'm struggling to find any examples of rings that are not polynomial identity (PI) rings. I was wondering if someone could point me in the general direction? I've messed around with the Weyl algebra and quaternions but I can't prove definitively whether they're PI rings or not.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is a "PI ring" the same as a ring which is a principal ideal domain? (i.e every ideal is generated by one element).

Comment: @DionelJaime no it's something else entirely.

Comment: @CyclotomicField what is it then? ...

Comment: @DionelJaime It's a polynomial identity ring just like the title states. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_ring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example is the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}\langle X_1, X_2, \ldots\rangle$, which is the free ring on $\mathbb{N}$ generators.

To see this, note that for all $N$, the obvious inclusion $f : \mathbb{Z}\langle X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N \rangle \to \mathbb{Z}\langle X_1, X_2, \ldots\rangle$ has a left inverse $g$ - for example, the one sending all $X_j$ to $0$ for $j > N$. So if we had $P \in \mathbb{Z}\langle X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N \rangle$ such that for all $a_1, \ldots, a_N \in R$, $P(a_1, \ldots, a_N) = 0$, then we would have $f(P) = P(x_1, \ldots, x_N)= 0$. Then we’d have $g(f(P)) = P = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> I've messed around with the Weyl algebra and quaternions but I can't prove definitively whether they're PI rings or not.

From theorem 1 in **Kaplansky, Irving. "Rings with a polynomial identity." Selected Papers and Other Writings (1995): 59.**, a right primitive ring which satisfies a polynomial identity has to be finite dimensional over its center. The Weyl algebra is right primitive but is infinite dimensional over its center.  That is why it does not satisfy a polynomial identity.

On the other hand, there is the famous embedding of $\mathbb H$ into $M_2(\mathbb C)$, and of course, this matrix ring satisfies the [standard identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_ring#Examples) so of course the subring does too.

Comment: Thank you! Just out of interest, in Kaplansky's paper he used "primitive algebra" in place of "primitive ring", is there any noticable difference between these two things?

Comment: @William pretty sure it just meant the primitive ring was also and algebra, but it wouldn’t hurt to double check. The paper is free to view

Comment: "We prove the main theorem of the paper not only for division rings, but more generally for primitive algebras in the sense of Jacobson."  I believe [this is what he is talking about](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969205?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A024ad56811dc2dcdd189d264ca3c2e2e&seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents). It's free up to a limited number of articles a month. It confirms that we're just talking about algebras which are right primitive as rings.